# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Cannot find scanner class

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, persistence

I have a web-app built with Thymeleaf and i want to connect it with my SqlServer DB; i created the persistence.xml and it is recognized, but during the server startup, i have the next trace:

```
13:35:01,355 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."vp301b-ear.ear/vp301b.war#unidadPersistencia": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."vp301b-ear.ear/vp301b.war#unidadPersistencia": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Cannot find scanner class. hibernate.ejb.resource_scanner=org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Cannot find scanner class. hibernate.ejb.resource_scanner=org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildScanner(Ejb3Configuration.java:406)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:593)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner from [Module "deployment.vp301b-ear.ear.vp301b.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildScanner(Ejb3Configuration.java:403)
    ... 9 more
```

I tried to change the hibernate version, modify the persistence.xml, delete and add manually the hibernate jars in my jboss directory, search this error... but nothing worked.

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <persistence-unit name="unidadPersistencia">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
         <class>my entity</class>
         <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="hibernate.cfg.xml" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="MY DRIVER"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="DATABASE"/> 
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="USER"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="PWD"/>
         </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Hibernate and persistence dependencies on pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

PROBLEM UPDATE:

After adding the dependencies indicated by mm6, the trace has changed, the new trace is the following:

```
15:07:14,589 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."vp301b-ear.ear/vp301b.war#unidadPersistencia": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."vp301b-ear.ear/vp301b.war#unidadPersistencia": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/util/ClassLoaderHelper
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/util/ClassLoaderHelper
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<init>(Ejb3Configuration.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.internal.util.ClassLoaderHelper from [Module "deployment.vp301b-ear.ear.vp301b.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception looks like it wants you to use AnnotationConfiguration and you are missing dependencies, which are still being included by jboss and its not using what you have in your jar.Try with below dependency:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: thanks, it worked but now the error trace is different, I updated the question, i am finding a dependency for solving this.

Comment: @AngelGonzalezPena try to add the `javassist` dependency, updated the ans.

Comment: Check Whether duplicate files added to an archive (jar, war, ear, etc.) using the jar, war, or ear tasks are added (or merged) by default. Try recompiling.